# How to deal with NA's while creating my own function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, na

I'm wondering how to deal with NA-values while creating my own function within R.

My code as follows:

```
# The function is simple:

function.BHR <-function(x) prod(1+x)-1

# The structure of the data.frame:    
dat <- t(data.frame(
  "A"=c(20:29/100),
  "B"=c(35:44/100),
  "C"=c(20:29/100),
  "E"=c(50:57/100,NA,NA),
  "E"=c(45:51/100,NA,NA,NA))

apply(dat,2,function.BHR)
```

The simple apply function delivers NA's for the last three columns. Instead of this
it should apply the function of all not-NA values. Hence:

```
  for column 8: 
  function.BHR(c(0.27,0.42,0.27,0.57))
[1] 2.595799

for column 9: 
  function.BHR(c(0.28,0.43,0.28))
[1] 1.342912

for column 10: 
  function.BHR(c(0.29,0.44,0.29))
[1] 1.396304
```

Thanks in advance!

Georg

Comment: I find your use of parentheses... disturbing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use the `na.rm` argument of `prod`. See `?prod` for details:

```
function.BHR <-function(x) { prod(1+x, na.rm=TRUE)-1 }

apply(dat, 2, function.BHR)

# [1] 3.228200 3.389747 3.556183 3.727619 3.904166 4.085938 4.273048 2.595799 1.342912 1.396304
```

Comment: That is even better, although my strategy is a bit more generic as it also works if the function you call inside your own function does not support `na.rm` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Change your function to remove the `NA`:

```
function.BHR <-function(x) {
   x = x[!is.na(x)]
   (prod((1+x))-1)
}

> apply(dat,2,function.BHR)
 [1] 3.228200 3.389747 3.556183 3.727619 3.904166 4.085938 4.273048 2.595799
 [9] 1.342912 1.396304
```

`is.na` returns a logical vector telling which values are `NA`, the `!` (NOT) operator inverts this logical vector, i.e. `TRUE` for a valid value, `FALSE` for `NA`. Using this vector for indexing will only return the valid values.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `logarithms` that'll turn the `product` to `sums` with which you can use `colSums` which is vectorised and is *much faster* than looping with `apply`:

```
exp(colSums(log(dat+1), na.rm=TRUE))-1
# [1] 3.228200 3.389747 3.556183 3.727619 3.904166 4.085938 4.273048 2.595799 1.342912 1.396304
```